# Intrinsic Camera Parameters to OpenGL Perspective Matrix: Near Far Parameters?

Tags: opencv, opengl, camera-calibration, perspectivecamera, pose-estimation

I am developing an Augmented Reality application that overlays graphics on to the camera image.  Using the OpenCV Pose Estimator, and the Intrinsic Camera Parameters from the device itself, I'm able to generate a pretty good OpenCV Camera Matrix and OpenGL Perspective Matrix that yield reasonable results.

However, my solution, and all similar ones that I've examine on this forum and other Internet locations, simply use some somewhat arbitrary values (typically 1.0 and 100) for the Perspective Matrix Near and Far Parameters.

However, while this is typically OK if the objects of interest are not too close, it become more inaccurate and a source of distortion when the objects are close to the view point.

Effectively, as these two parameters (near, far) are adjusted, the vanishing point of the perspective changes.

Does anyone have a more sound approach to deriving the Near and Far parameters from the available data?

Comment: do you apply some kind of fake-lens-distortion during rendering?

Answer (score 5):

The near and far plane have no effect on the perspective. They only change where the front and back clipping planes are placed.

You can convince yourself that this is the case by looking at a typical projection matrix. Using the definitions:

- `asp`: Aspect ratio.
- `t2`: Tangent of half view angle.
- `n`: Near distance.
- `f`: Far distance.

The projection matrix is then:

```
    [ 1 / (asp * t2)  0       0                  0                   ]
P = [ 0               1 / t2  0                  0                   ]
    [ 0               0       (n + f) / (n - f)  2 * n * f / (n - f) ]
    [ 0               0       -1                 0                   ]
```

Applying this to a vector gives:

```
    [ x ]   [ x / (asp * t2)                      ]
P * [ y ] = [ y / t2                              ]
    [ z ]   [ (z * (n + f) + 2 * n * f) / (n - f) ]
    [ 1 ]   [ -z                                  ]
```

After perspective division, the vector is:

```
[ x / (-z * asp * t2)                  ]
[ y / (-z * t2)                        ]
[ -(n + f + (2 * n * f) / z) / (n - f) ]
[ 1                                    ]
```

As you can see, the `x` and `y` component of the resulting vector, which determine the position of the vertex in the window (or more precisely, in NDC space), do not depend on the values of the near and far distance. The near and far values only control the mapping of the z coordinate in eye space to the z (depth) value in NDC space.

Comment: the distance between near and far however influences the precision of depth-buffering! So if `near´ parameter is reduced, pixel of vertices near the ´far´ plane might be rendered wrong.

Comment: Hi Retro:  Thanks for your excellent comment.  Yes, I am mistaken and you are correct: the near-far parameters do NOT play a role in the image perspective (or location of vanishing points).  I have placed an image of my situation here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/VnLB6.png.  No matter what corrections I apply to the X,Y and Z translation and rotation, my OpenGL cube never quite properly overlays the actual Rubik Cube. I still believe it is a perspective problem, but now I'm thinking perhaps the root case is in the field of view angles intrinsic camera calibration data.  Thanks for you help.

Comment: Hi Retro, thanks a lot for the awesome answer, but are you sure about term `2 * n * f / (n - f)`. It would make way more sense if it comes with the negative sign. Just substitute `z` coordinate with `n` and `f` and it would map into `-1` and `1`, respectively. Otherwise, it will be `-(n + 3f) / (n - f)` and `-(3n + f) / (n - f)`, that is a bit more weird.

Answer (score 1):

It appears from the image that you posted in the comment above that your intrinsic camera parameters in general and your field of view in particular are not correct.  There are several numerical methods of estimating the camera parameters.  However, their accuracy decreases with increasing complexity.

If you just want to know the field of view, you can calculate it by creating a target with a 3x3 field of small, evenly spaced dots.  The target should be large enough to fill most of the image at the range at which you'll be working.  If you have a small target, you can move the camera closer as long as it is still in focus.  The dots should be relatively small so that you can estimate the positions of the centers accurately if you're doing it by hand.  Larger dots should be used if you're estimating their locations using a computer program.

Most of the dots are for alignment.  The horizontal field of view can be calculated from the most widely space dots in the center horizontal line.  The vertical field of view can be calculated in a similar manner.  The dots in the center and corners should be used to make sure the camera image plane is centered and parallel to the target.  (If it proves difficult to get the dots to line up with the rows and columns of your image, you may need a more sophisticated camera model.)

Once the target has been set up, the horizontal field of view can be calculated.

- Let Z = range to the target in meters.
- Let D = distance between the horizontal dots in meters.
- Let w = width the image in pixels.
- Let x = distance between the horizontal dots in pixels.

Then,

HFOV = 2 * arctan((D * (w / x) / 2) / Z).

A similar calculation applies to the vertical field of view.

We used this simple method to calibrate our cameras on the DARPA Unmanned Ground Vehicle project back in the 90's and it worked pretty well.

Hope that helps.